# When doing an app update, does Bundle ID Suffix remain the same?

Tags: ipad

I am doing an update to my iPad App and iTunes Connect is asking me to enter the Bundle ID Suffix. I am wondering if it needs to be a different one from the original Bundle ID Suffix, or should it remain the same as in the original version?

Thanks!
Kat

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an update, iTunes Connect does not ask for a new Bundle ID suffix.  It only asks for new version number and some update description text.  The Bundle ID has to stay the same for a submission to be an update.  If you are on a form asking for a bundle ID, you are not on the app update web page or form.  Perhaps you are looking at a web page or form for creating a new app, or for updating the details of either the app or the update, on which you don't have to change anything.